# How to configure Expo development build with Expo Router? (Unable to load script error)

Tags: react-native, expo, eas, expo-router

I am trying to set up an Expo React Native project that uses Expo Router as well as some native code (specifically react-native-nfc-manager & expo-camera/next). However I encounter a problem when trying to run a development build. As soon as I open the development build on Android I get the following error:

```
There was a problem loading the project.

This development build encountered the following error.

Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.

jniLoadScriptFromAssets

CatalystInstanceImpl.java

loadScript FromAssets

CatalystInstanceImpl.java

loadScript

JSBundleLoader.java

runJSBundle

CatalystInstanceImpl.java

createReactContext

ReactInstanceManager.java

lambda$runCreateReactContextOnNew Thread$2

ReactInstanceManager.java

$r8$lambda$AwGS8CysOZmWJw3kRVARHQvw9Ew

run

run

Thread.java
```

The easiest way I have found to reproduce this is to run the following:

- `npx create-expo-app@latest --template tabs@50`
- `npx expo prebuild`
- `npx eas build -p android --profile development`
  Then after downloading the dev-build start the dev server by running
- `npx expo start -c`

This results in the error shown previously.

I would love to get some advice on how to continue.

Comment: I assume this is the new Expo version 50? I'm having the same issue as well.

Comment: I'm developing for Android, and if I install the dev client app, connect my phone to my development computer over USB and press "a" after running `npx expo start --dev-client`, the app successfully launches and loads the bundle even though it won't launch if I use a QR code. Doesn't fix the issue you referenced, but it could be a workaround.